# Problems with PlayN building

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, playn

I want to create a PlayN game, but in Eclipse I get this errors:

```
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): No response received after 60000  pom.xml /playn-payments-server  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.googlecode.gwt-flash:gwt-flash:jar:1.2 from http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of forplay-legacy has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.googlecode.gwt-flash:gwt-flash:jar:1.2 from/to forplay-legacy (http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo): No response received after 60000  pom.xml /playn-flash    line 21 Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer com.googlecode.gwt-flash:gwt-flash:jar:1.2 from http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of forplay-legacy has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.googlecode.gwt-flash:gwt-flash:jar:1.2 from/to forplay-legacy (http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo): No response received after 60000  pom.xml /playn-tests-flash  line 4  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): No response received after 60000  pom.xml /playn-payments-server  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0  pom.xml /playn-payments-server  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.googlecode.gwt-flash:gwt-flash:jar:1.2 pom.xml /playn-flash    line 21 Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact com.googlecode.gwt-flash:gwt-flash:jar:1.2 pom.xml /playn-tests-flash  line 4  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6    pom.xml /playn-payments-server  line 2  Maven Dependency Problem
Open quote is expected for attribute "rename-to" associated with an  element type  "module".    TestsFlashGame.gwt.xml  /playn-tests-flash/src/main/java/playn/tests    line 16 XML Problem
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Vukasin Manojlovic\.m2\repository\com\google\collections\google-collections\1.0\google-collections-1.0.jar'    playn-payments-server       Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Vukasin Manojlovic\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\gwt-flash\gwt-flash\1.2\gwt-flash-1.2.jar'    playn-flash     Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Vukasin Manojlovic\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\gwt-flash\gwt-flash\1.2\gwt-flash-1.2.jar'    playn-tests-flash       Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    playn-flash     Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    playn-payments-server       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    playn-tests-flash       Unknown Java Problem
```

What should I do? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your maven installation is not able to contact the central repository to resolve the dependencies listed, this is usually a connectivity issue.

Are you behind a proxy? If so, you can configure maven to access it on maven's settings.xml. (On windows it is on your user profile folder)

If still you are not able to download the dependencies automatically, you can always download them manually and install them to your local repository, issuing:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

For your first dependency should be something like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=google-collections.jar -DgroupId=com.google.collections -DartifactId=google-collections -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I have a problem only with this `Open quote is expected for attribute "rename-to" associated with an  element type  "module". TestsFlashGame.gwt.xml /playn-tests-flash/src/main/java/playn/tests line 16 XML Problem`. What should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you with this one, but being a different problem, you should open another question so it gets the attention it deserves